# Hosted or static front end CMS

Tags: cms, hosted

I need to develop an update for my company's website, and due to the rapid change in front-end software I am not sure what the state of the art is. I would prefer to use either a managed hosted or serverless solution, as we don't have the resources to play cat and mouse with hackers with a server.

The requirements are as follows:

- The ability to add rich text pages and blog posts with embedded media
- User signup and authentication for accessing company software downloads
- Support forum and/or ticket tracking system
- Pre-made templates
- The ability to add plugins for custom functionality
- Automatic patching, user data managed by hosting/cloud services
- Filter by IP address due to US export restrictions
- Fast and easy setup. Web development is not this company's focus.

WordPress would probably be a reasonable choice, however I have had terrible experiences with WordPress security in the past so I am hesitant to use it. The other options I have found are bubble.is (too limited) or FlameLink + FireBase (too immature).

I am aware that any plugins we develop will need to be secured and maintained by our team.

Any suggestions on how to proceed are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The goto site for all thingsCMS is [CMS matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org/). You can select requirements and have some recommended and then compare them. For instance, you might choose base don security. See [this page](http://cmsmatrix.org/matrix/cms-matrix?func=search) to do so.

Comment: It's been way too long since you used wordpress if you're dismissing it on security grounds.  If you keep up with updates diligently, you have no reason to be so worried.  Do you think ~30% of the world's  websites would use it if it was so unreliable?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on hosting a wordpress site, then using http://wpengine.com/ could be a good option as they have good support and mange upgrade, backups etc...

If alternatively you would prefer to be completely hands off and just want a good looking / performing site, but don't need custom branding. Then https://www.squarespace.com/ is a great option. https://www.wix.com/ is also another, but personally I prefer the website templates that Square Space have.

Comment: @John any comment on this answer? If you already found a solution, please answer your own question, to help others in future